# Labeling in SQL Server for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each order may include a hot or cold drink or both.
As in the table below.

| orderID | ProductID | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| am2 | 212 | cold drink |
| am2 | 51004 | hot drink |
| am2 | 10032 | hot drink |

I want it to be labeled "both" if an order contains both types of drinks, otherwise, it should be labeled as it is. As in the table below.
How should I write this query in SQL?

| orderID | label |
| --- | --- |
| am2 | both |

Comment: are there other possible values for column type ?

Comment: use a `GROUP BY` query and `CASE` expression to check for `COUNT()` of column `type`

Comment: @GuidoG   yes. column "type" has these values: "cold drink, hot drink, other drinks, and others". Is this what you mean?

Comment: I have more than two types in the 'type' column.
@Squirrel

Comment: So what is it when it's "cold, and hot, and other?" It's can't be "both" as that denotes it's 2 things, not 3.

Comment: you're right but here "hot" and "cold" are important for me.
If an order has cold, hot, and other, it should be labeled as "both".   
@Larnu

Comment: So if an order has two hot drinks you want both rows, or two hot drinks and 'other' you want 3 rows, but if it had two hot drinks, 'other' and a cold drink, you want 1 row with 'both' ?

Comment: @Stu for each order, I want just 1 label. if an order has a hot drink and a cold drink(or more than 1 of each one), label should be "both". if an order has a 'hot drink' and 'other' or just 'hot drink', label should be "hot drink", and also for 'cold drink'. if an order just has type 'other', label should be "other".

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you can do a group by with a case expression, and you could do this in an outer apply, like [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GOZYgqTE)  example

```
select o.orderID,
       o.ProductID,
       case when oo.coldcount > 0 and oo.hotcount > 0 then 'both' else o.type end
from   orders o
  outer apply ( select o2.orderID, 
                       sum (case when o2.type = 'cold drink' then 1 else 0 end) coldcount,
                       sum (case when o2.type = 'hot drink' then 1 else 0 end) hotcount
                from   orders o2
                where  o2.orderID = o.orderID
                group by o2.orderID
              ) oo
```

which results in this

| orderID | ProductID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| am2 | 212 | both |
| am2 | 51004 | both |
| am2 | 10032 | both |
| am3 | 51004 | hot drink |
| am3 | 10032 | hot drink |

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a little bit of conditional aggregation, assuming the *type* descriptions are as described:

```
select orderID, case when Min(both) != Max(both) then 'both' else Min(type) end [Label]
from t
cross apply (values(case when type in('hot drink', 'cold drink') then type end))b(both)
group by orderID
order by orderID;
```

Test [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jaWcYcl8)